# Psalms, difference between the Lord and his name?

Tags: psalms

Psalms 113:2; KJV;

> 2 Blessed be the name of the Lord **from this time forth and for evermore.**

Psalms 41:13; KJV;

> 13 Blessed be the Lord God of Israel **from everlasting, and to everlasting**. Amen, and Amen.

What is the difference between the Lord and His Name?

N.B: Lord is blessed from everlasting to everlasting, while Name of the Lord is blessed from this time forth and for evermore.

The Lord and his name both mentioned in Psalms 113:1.

Psalms 113:1; KJV;

> 113 **Praise ye the Lord**. Praise, O ye servants of the Lord, **praise the name of the Lord.**

Answer (score 2):

As best I can work out, "The name of the LORD" is used in three subtlety different ways (some of these overlap considerably):

**1. As a synonym for the LORD Himself**

- Job 1:21 - And he said, “Naked I came from my mother’s womb, and naked shall I return. The LORD gave, and the LORD has taken away; blessed be the name of the LORD.”
- Isa 24:15 - Therefore in the east give glory to the LORD; in the coastlands of the sea, give glory to the **name of the LORD, the God of Israel**. [This is also #3 as well]
- Ps 113:1 - Praise **the LORD**! Praise, O servants of the LORD, praise **the name of the LORD**! [This is also #3 as well]
- Isa 48:1 - Hear this, O house of Jacob, who are called by the name of Israel, and who came from the waters of Judah, who swear by the **name of the LORD and confess the God of Israel**, but not in truth or right.

**2. When acting on delegated authority from the LORD**

- Ps 118:26 - Blessed is **he who comes in the name of the LORD**! We bless you from the house of the LORD.
- Deut 18:22 - when a **prophet speaks in the name of the LORD**, if the word does not come to pass or come true, that is a word that the LORD has not spoken; the prophet has spoken it presumptuously. You need not be afraid of him.
- 1 Kings 18:24 - And you call upon the name of your god, and **I will call upon the name of the LORD**, and the God who answers by fire, he is God.” And all the people answered, “It is well spoken.”
- Micah 5:4 - And he shall stand and shepherd his flock in the **strength of the LORD**, in the majesty of the name of the LORD his God. And they shall dwell secure, for now he shall be great to the ends of the earth.
- 2 Chron 33:18 - Now the rest of the acts of Manasseh, and his prayer to his God, and the words of the seers who **spoke to him in the name of the LORD**, the God of Israel, behold, they are in the Chronicles of the Kings of Israel.
- 1 Sam 17:45 - Then David said to the Philistine, “You come to me with a sword and with a spear and with a javelin, but **I come to you in the name of the LORD** of hosts, the God of the armies of Israel, whom you have defied. [This is also #1 as well]

**3. As a synonym for the reputation, glory, and character of the LORD**

- 2 Chron 2:4 - Behold, I am about to build a house for **the name of the LORD my God and dedicate it to Him** for the burning of incense of sweet spices before Him, and for the regular arrangement of the showbread, and for burnt offerings morning and evening, on the Sabbaths and the new moons and the appointed feasts of the LORD our God, as ordained forever for Israel. [This is also #1 as well]
- 1 Chron 22:19 - Now set your mind and heart to seek the LORD your God. Arise and build the sanctuary of the LORD God, so that the ark of the covenant of the LORD and the holy vessels of God may be brought into a house built for **the name of the LORD**.” [This is also #1 as well]
- Lev 24:16 - Whoever blasphemes the **name of the LORD** shall surely be put to death. All the congregation shall stone him. The sojourner as well as the native, when he blasphemes the Name, shall be put to death.
- Isa 59:19 - So they shall fear the **name of the LORD** from the west, **and his glory** from the rising of the sun; for he will come like a rushing stream, which the wind of the LORD drives.
- Isa 18:7 - At that time tribute will be brought to the LORD of hosts from a people tall and smooth, from a people feared near and far, a nation mighty and conquering, whose land the rivers divide, to Mount Zion, the **place of the name of the LORD** of hosts.
- Isa 60:9 - For the coastlands shall hope for me, the ships of Tarshish first, to bring your children from afar, their silver and gold with them, **for the name of the LORD** your God, and for the Holy One of Israel, because he has made you beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

The two significant Hebrew words here mean "*to praise*" or "to boast", and "*name*", "reputation", "fame", or "glory".

So "Praise ye the Lord … praise the name of the Lord" could mean to boast to the world about God himself, and about God's accomplishments.

Compare with a parent bragging about a child's character (respectful, generous, intelligent, etc.), and accomplishments (university degree, professional job, recognized as a benefactor to the community, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The שֵׁם "Shem" (Name) in **[Psalm 113:1-2]** is a proclamation of believers : יְהֹוָה "Y-HV-H" (Yihyeh, Hoveh, Hayah).

- "He will be" (יִהְיֶה)
- "He is" (הוֹוֶה)
- "He was" (הָיָה)

[Y-HV-H (יְהֹוָה)]

> Praise [the]-Name of YHVH! (הַ֜לְלוּ אֶת־שֵׁם יְהֹוָה)

as stated in [Tehillim 113:1].

---

**[WHAT] is יְהֹוָה YHVH?**

- *YHVH* remains Eternally (as described in His Name) עֹשֶׂךָ "Your-Maker" **[Isaiah 44:2]**;
  "Your-God" אֱלֹהֶ֔יךָ **[Exodus 20:2]**.
- *YHVH* was called אֵל שַׁדָּי "El Shaddai" by Avraham, Yitschaq, Yaaqov - as stated in **[Exodus 6:3]**.
- Since אֵל שַׁדָּי "El Shaddai" always has been/will be humanity's Maker & God, Moshe described Him as : יְהֹוָה *YHVH*.

Answer (score 1):

Names are used to describe someone or something. We can see Moses asking God so.

Exodus 3:13-14 ESV

> Then Moses said to God, “If I come to the people of Israel and say to them, ‘The God of your fathers has sent me to you,’ and they ask me, ‘What is his name?’ what shall I say to them?” God said to Moses, “I AM WHO I AM.” And he said, “Say this to the people of Israel: ‘I AM has sent me to you.’”

I try to bring reason to the meaning of what this means by using scripture to interpret the names God has listed about himself.

I am not a man.

Hosea 11:9 ESV

> I will not execute my burning anger;
> I will not again destroy Ephraim;
> for I am God and not a man,
> the Holy One in your midst,
> and I will not come in wrath.

I am the Lord

Leviticus 11:45 ESV

> For I am the LORD who brought you up out of the land of Egypt to be your God. You shall therefore be holy, for I am holy.”

I am God

Genesis 26:24 ESV

> And the LORD appeared to him the same night and said, “I am the God of Abraham your father. Fear not, for I am with you and will bless you and multiply your offspring for my servant Abraham's sake.”

difference between the Lord and his name?

The question should be reworded to say, similarity between the Lord and his names?